# VB How do I make an array of a user defined type? (Fields)

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have forgotten how to make an array or whatever out of 8 fields. It looks something like Array.Subcategory[x] afterwards but i've forgotten what its called and how to do it.
It needs to be 1 array with multiple entries but each entry have 8 sub entries.

So for a group of people

1 array entry will contain:

```
Name
Eye colour
Haircolour
Age
Balls
Smell
???
```

One array will contain all this data for each array entry.

cheers

Comment: Are you trying to create a class? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973814.aspx

Comment: Consider Generic list of Objects (of your type)

Comment: i agree with Andrew, you want a class, not an array.

Comment: Could you save me some time and give me an example of a class? I'll give you the answer credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a [class in VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973814.aspx) like this:

```
public class Entry
    public Name as String
    public EyeColour as String
    public Haircolour as String
    public Age as Integer
    public Balls as Integer
    public Smell as String
end class
```

Then create a [`List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`Array`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx) holding entries like this:

```
public ListOfEntries as List(of Entry) = new List(of Entry)

public ArrayOfEntries(10) as Entry
```

Use it like this:

```
dim e as Entry = new Entry
e.Name = "Test"
e.EyeColour = "Blue"
' add new object to list
ListOfEntries.Add(e)
' add new object at position 0
ArrayOfEntries(0) = e
```

Another possibility would be to use a [Structure (used-defined data type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cec05s9z.aspx):

```
' a record of data
public structure Entry
    public Name as String
    public EyeColour as Integer
    '...
end structure
' array of entries
public Entries(10) as Entry
' usage like in the class example
dim e = new Entry
e.Name = "Test"
e.EyeColour = 5
Entries(0) = e
```

Comment: That was it. Nice one m8

Comment: there are a few places where properties and public fields are handled differently, so those ought read `Public Property Name...`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with types also, which avoids some of the initialization hassels with classes in arrays:

```
Type foo
    Name as String
    EyeColour as Integer
    ...
End Type

Dim bar() As foo
```